# Zurb Foundation 6 Primary Color Variable

Tags: sass, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

Looking at `_settings.scss` in Zurb Foundation 6 the SASS variable `$primary-color` appears not to have any assigned value. My question is does `$foundation-palettes` primary equate to `$primary-color`?

```
$foundation-palette: (
  primary: #2199e8,
  secondary: #777,
  success: #3adb76,
  warning: #ffae00,
  alert: #ec5840,
);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does. There is a `@mixin` in `scss/util/_color.scss` that takes care of this for us:

```
/// Transfers the colors in the `$foundation-palette` variable into the legacy color variables, such as `$primary-color` and `$secondary-color`. Call this mixin below the Global section of your settings file to properly migrate your codebase.
@mixin add-foundation-colors() {
  @if map-has-key($foundation-palette, primary) {
    $primary-color: map-get($foundation-palette, primary) !global;
  }
  @if map-has-key($foundation-palette, secondary) {
    $secondary-color: map-get($foundation-palette, secondary) !global;
  }
  @if map-has-key($foundation-palette, success) {
    $success-color: map-get($foundation-palette, success) !global;
  }
  @if map-has-key($foundation-palette, warning) {
    $warning-color: map-get($foundation-palette, warning) !global;
  }
  @if map-has-key($foundation-palette, alert) {
    $alert-color: map-get($foundation-palette, alert) !global;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes they are equal. $primary-color is legacy stuff just use the color palettes.